# Ubuntu for Tablet PC Artists?

Tags: graphics-tablet, stylus

Is there a Tablet PC version of Ubuntu for artists who draw with stylus in paint programs? Has anyone tried it on Asus B121, HP Slate or other "drawing tablets"? Please provide links to articles or forums that discuss Ubuntu for Penabled Tablets and Digital Artists. Happy New Year!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are most likely interested in Ubuntu Studio which is set up specifically for creative work:

http://ubuntustudio.org/

http://ubuntustudio.org/tour/graphics/

Both Inkscape and Gimp work with pressure sensitive input devices.

It looks like the Asus B121 pressure sensitivity has been supported since ubuntu quantal. Not sure about the HP Slate or others, but anything using Wacom hardware/drivers should be well supported.